# Get value of field with lombok builder

Tags: java, lombok, builder, anti-patterns

Is it possible to retrieve the value of a field on a builder which was generated by lombok?

```
final var builder = Something.builder();

try {
    // ... something that might break
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    builder.error("Something went wrong.");
    builder.success(false);
}

// don't continue if the builder is already marked as not-successful
if (builder.isSuccess() != null && builder.isSuccess()) {
 // ... do some more work / set more fields on the builder
}

return builder.build();
```

It seems that lombok builders do not expose getters for the fields they can build, so in the code above, `builder.isSuccess()` doesn't exist. Is it possible to do this, or is it an anti-pattern?

The alternative is to return from the `catch` block, but IMO multiple returns in a method lead to harder to follow code, so I would like to avoid that and just return the builder at the end of the method.

Comment: You should think about the meaning of word builder. Builder guesses what before command .build() your object is not consistent.

Comment: Do you have a constructive answer? I realize the intent of `builder`, but it seems reasonable to ask a builder "what value does this field have right now". If not, and there is no way, or it's an anti-pattern, that is fine -- that's all I'm asking. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's an antipattern.  Before command .build() your object is not consistent you shouldn't see its intermediate state

Comment: That is a valid answer. If you'd like to add it as one, and elaborate, that'd be fine by me.

Comment: That's complete